# restrict write access to folder using .htaccess and ip address

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, .htaccess

We would like to restrict 'write' access to a directory just to users accessing the site from our network static ip address.

This example works to restrict access to a folder from an ip,

```
Deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Obviously however folders like wp-content needs to be accessed from all ip addresses. We just want to stop it being edited unless the user is on our network.

We don't want to change file permissions as that would stop the built in wordpress auto upgrade feature working or uploading files using the browser.

Is that possible?

Thanks
Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Any user from any IP cannot "write" into a directory. Only GET, POST etc http requests are handled by the web server. Its the scripts running on server which can or cannot write into a directory.
For wordpress etc, you should first see which are all methods that write into directories. I'm not familiar with wordpress but say it has a upgrade url like, `example.com/wp-admin/upgrade.php?blah=blah`

Then you can put a `.htaccess` rule to allow `wp-admin/upgrade.php` only for specific IPs. You get the idea.